# How to define a Prototype of a Function with parameters that have default values?

Tags: c++, function, function-prototypes

A have a function with a prototype of:

```
void arryprnt(int[], string, int, string, string);
```

And a definition of:

```
void arryprnt(int[] a, string intro, int len, string sep=", ", string end=".") {
// stuff
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
arryprnt(jimmy, "PSEUDOJIMMY: ", 15);
```

...When I make that call to arryprnt, I get a compiler error saying that I've used too few arguments, based off what the prototype says. "Okay," I'm thinking, "The compiler doesn't know that some of arryprnt's parameters have default values. I'll just copy the parameters from the definition into the prototype." And I did, however, I got a compiler error telling me that I was calling arryprnt with *too many* arguments! I could just explicitly specify all the arguments, but is there any way to call it without specifying all the arguments?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should put the default arguments in the prototype, not the definition like this:

```
void arryprnt(int[] a, string intro, int len, string sep=", ", string end=".");
```

and the make the definition without them:

```
void arryprnt(int[] a, string intro, int len, string sep, string end) {
    // ...
}
```

BTW: on another note. It is considered good practice to pass objects which larger than an int by **const reference**. While this isn't appropriate for **all** situations, it is appropriate for most and avoids copying things unnecessarily. For example:

```
void func(const std::string &s) {
    // do some read-only operation with s.
}

func("hello world");
```

Comment: Umm... Somehow that didn't work. I'm getting the "too many arguments" error.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you are doing something wrong. I'm not sure what would cause that issue, but this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but below code worked fine.

prototyping:

```
void arryprnt(int[], string, int, string = ", ", string=". ");
```

Definition:

```
void arryprnt(int a[], string intro, int len, string sep, string endd)
//stuff
```

when there are default arguments for a function, then best is to declare them at prototype, not in function definition. below code didnt work,

prototype:

```
void arryprnt(int[], string, int, string = ", ", string=". ");
```

definition:

```
void arryprnt(int a[], string intro, int len, string sep = ", ", string endd = ". ")
//stuff
```

Comment: Downvoting because this answer does not add anything to what is already said in the existing answer.